# Count and echo total $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

How do I count how many times the users use/login `$_SESSION` and echo the total system count? (Assuming `$_SESSION['login`])

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean, if i login with session, the session get save itill i destroy him, so i want to count the times i login to session, how do i do that?

Comment: Save on file/database each time an user logs in, then count

Comment: You mean add to file.xml tag named <count></count> and add variable++ to count each time user login?

Comment: If it's easier to you. I'd rather use a database, so I can track which user, when, how many time, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store it in a `$_SESSION` variable but it's unreliable and users could easily reset the session cookie. I'd do something like this instead:

```
if (user_logged_in)
{
   $query = "UPDATE some_table SET total_logins = total_logins + 1 WHERE user_id = $userID";
   $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
}
```

Hope this helps!